# In CMD compiler environment ,leading-in myself-written modules tips “ No module named ”

Tags: python, python-import

Under the project directory are two packages,'luomo' and 'uitlbt'.
When I want to call \luomo\E.py in \uitlbt\D.py, 
in CMD compilation mode,  will prompt "No module named luomo".
I made some attempts but failed,
I want to ask，In the CMD compilation mode,
How to Run D.py Successfully，
thanks.

Directory screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1SPv.png

Wrong screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1pjk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```